# why in java, if "*" is given in argument with the main method main in command-line compilation, this is considered as an "a"

Tags: java

Why in java, if "*" is given in argument with the main method main in command-line compilation, this is considered as an "a"

```
class Bonjour {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0].charAt(0));
    }
}
```

```
C:\Users\cri\Desktop>javac Bonjour.java

C:\Users\cri\Desktop>java Bonjour *
a

C:\Users\cri\Desktop>java Bonjour +
+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just your command shell replacing `*` with all matching file names before Java even gets to see it.

The result is the same as if you manually typed something like

```
java Bonjour aFileInTheCurrentDirectory.tx anotherOne oneMore zeLastFile
```

Try quoting it to avoid that.

Not sure how Windows shell works, maybe

```
java Bonjour "*"
```